# Avoid returning Java.lang.Object, instead convert it to a specific type

Tags: java

for a university project I have to fix the maintenance of a software. Kiuwan reports the problem "Avoid returning Java.lang.Object, instead convert it to a specific type." on many methods and to solve all the problems I should redesign the software from head to head!
Is there a way to circumvent Kiuwan and "solve" this problem?
This is an example of method to fix:

```
public Object popupMenu(Object component) {
    return ThinletLayoutInterface.popupMenu(component, this);
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Just change the return type to what you want to return? Do you understand what every part of `public Object popupMenu(Object component)` means? If not, that should be your question (for which you should probably head to Google or a textbook first). On the other hand, if there's some reason you can't just change the return type to what you want, you should elaborate on that and provide a [mcve].

Comment: The Kiuwan analyzer warns me as an "Avoid returning Java.lang.Object" problem and for this reason the maintenance value is low. Now I can not change the signature of all the methods they have as a kind of return Object because it would cost me to redesign the system. Is there a way to elude Kiuwan by replacing Object with something that functions exactly like Object?

Comment: If you need to redesign the system to avoid returning Object, that points to a badly designed system which most likely **should** be redesigned. No, inheritance doesn't work like that - Object is the only class that all classes inherit from, you can't replace it with another class that will also work for objects of all types.

Answer (score 0):

I really have no idea what ThinletLayoutInterface does. but if you absolutely **KNOW** on each call to this method what type you expect to get back, you can cheat, with some cheesyness and do

```
public <T> T popupMenu(Class<T> cls, Object component) {
     return (T) ThinletLayoutInterface.popupMenu(component, this);
}
```

and then call it like this, assuming as an example you know this invocation should return a Widget.

```
Widget w = populateMenu(Widget.class, myComponent);
```

This puts all the burden of type safety on the caller, and is really, as i said, a cheat.